# Communicating with ports using ioperm() in embedded device

Tags: c, linux, io, embedded, port

There is a problem with the following code. I need it to give access to the ports 0x300 to 0x307 so i do this:

```
#ifdef LINUX
if(ioperm(PORT1,9,1)==-1) printf("Error in ioperm()");
#endif
```

Where PORT1=0x300.

then i do this:

```
int j5inp(unsigned int addr){

#ifdef DOS
return inp(addr);
#endif
#ifdef LINUX
return inb(addr);
#endif
}

void j5outp(unsigned int addr, unsigned int val){

#ifdef DOS
    outp(addr,val);
#endif
#ifdef LINUX
    outb(val,addr);
#endif
}

/************/
hrd_check()
{
    j5outp(PCHECK,0xAA);
    if (j5inp(PCHECK)!=0xAA) return(0);
    j5outp(PCHECK,0x55);
    if (j5inp(PCHECK)!=0x55) return(0);

 return(1);
 }
```

where PCHECK=0x307.

I have tested this and i found that i am able to retrieve the value 0xAA from the port after i sent it, but the second one (0x55) fails because inb() still returns 0xAA.

Am i doing anything wrong? can this be a hardware problem? Should i try calling the ioperm() function for every call to inb() or should i try using iopl() ?

by the way, the board i am using is the advantech PCM-3342

Comment: The `inp(2)` manpage mentions that there are `_p` variants that pause until the IO is complete -- do you need to use these instead? (You should not need to call `ioperm()` or `iopl()` on every use -- these set a flag in the process's `thread_struct`.)

Comment: You mean that inb will not pause when they are called? how does that work? The purpose of what i am attempting is to migrate this program from DOS to linux. I need the way i access those ports to have the same type of performance that the fucntions inp() and outp() have on DOS. I will look into the *_p functions, thanks.

Comment: I left the question about the `_p` variants as a comment rather than answer because I'm just shooting in the dark here -- but I wouldn't be surprised if writing to IO ports takes some time, and `outb_p()` would take longer to execute than `outb()`, but the device might be able to report an updated value with the next `inb()` after having waited for the output to really work first. Big guess, but hopefully easy to test...

Comment: BTW, in addition to delay possibilities there's no rule that says hardware output ports have to support readback.  Some do, and some don't.  If there is no read support, sometimes you get funny values due to bus capacitance, etc.  Also, your port may have mode configuration that needs to be set, or drivers or potentially conflicting other peripherals that need to be configured out of the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i guess this is one of those problems that simply goes away. I believe i corrected a little bug that i was sure was unrelated to this problem. But when i did it the problem went away.

I would give a better description of how i solved it but i don't really know how i did it.